# Entity Framework Many to Many, mapping table & duplication. Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

There are questions/answers of a similar nature to what I'm about to ask, however none of them have a full answer. (Sorry if i missed something while searching)

DB Structure:

```
public class ApplciationDbContext : DbContext()
{

    public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Tag_Photo_XREF> TagPhoto_XREF { get; set; }       

}

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Tag : BaseEntity
{
    public Tag()
    {
        Photos = new HashSet<Tag_Photo_XREF>();
    }
    public string TagText { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag_Photo_XREF> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class Tag_Photo_XREF : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid TagId { get; set; }
    public Guid PhotoId { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public virtual Photo Photo { get; set; }
}

public class Photo : BaseEntity
{
    public Photo()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag_Photo_XREF>();
        GeneratedTags = new HashSet<GeneratedTag_Photo_XREF>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag_Photo_XREF> Tags { get; set; }        

   }
}
```

I see how all of this hangs together but my questions are:
1) How to prevent duplicate insert primary on Tags.
2) How to do the insert in the first place? Do i do:

```
Photo p = new Photo();
Tag_Photo_XREF tagPhotoXref1 = new Tag_Photo_XREF();
tagPhotoXref1.Tag = new Tag() { TagText = "...1" };

Tag_Photo_XREF tagPhotoXref2 = new Tag_Photo_XREF();
tagPhotoXref2.Tag = new Tag() { TagText = "...2" };

Tag_Photo_XREF tagPhotoXref3 = new Tag_Photo_XREF();
tagPhotoXref3.Tag = new Tag() { TagText = "...3" };
p.Tags.Add(tagPhotoXref1);
p.Tags.Add(tagPhotoXref2);
p.Tags.Add(tagPhotoXref3);

dbContext.Photos.Add(p);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

or something like:

```
Photo p = new Photo();
Tag_Photo_XREF tagPhotoXref1 = new Tag_Photo_XREF();
tagPhotoXref1.Tag = new Tag() { TagText = "...1" };
tagPhotoXref1.Photo = p;

Tag_Photo_XREF tagPhotoXref2 = new Tag_Photo_XREF();
tagPhotoXref2.Tag = new Tag() { TagText = "...2" };
tagPhotoXref1.Photo = p;

Tag_Photo_XREF tagPhotoXref3 = new Tag_Photo_XREF();
tagPhotoXref3.Tag = new Tag() { TagText = "...3" };
tagPhotoXref1.Photo = p;

dbContext.TagPhoto_XREF.Add(tagPhotoXref1);
dbContext.TagPhoto_XREF.Add(tagPhotoXref2);
dbContext.TagPhoto_XREF.Add(tagPhotoXref3);
dbContext.Photos.Add(p);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Both ways seem very messy and over complicated. This would all be very different if i didn't need the Score property on the Linking table.

Another questions in relation to this is that if i have multiple connections to my ApplicationDbContext from different users how to you prevent the same tag being insert (text  must be unique)

Maybe I'm missing the point and way over complicating it.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Is this sample example? In the `Photo` entity you have `GeneratedTags = new HashSet<GeneratedTag_Photo_XREF>();` but I don't see `GeneratedTags` property.

Comment: @Leron yep, i copied this and deleted a lot of other properties..ignore that in the ctor its just unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when you have an Xref table between two other tables, you don't use an identity / surrogate primary key. The primary key of the Xref would be a composite key of both entity keys: in your case it would be TagId, PhotoId

Now considering you are using a BaseEntity to define the primary key as an identity on all entities, you do not have that luxury (unless you change your code). The only solutions that I can see would be to put a unique index on those two columns (you can do this using migrations). The other option is just to prevent duplicates using business logic in your application.

For your other question you would usually do something like:

```
Photo p = new Photo();
Tag tag1 = new Tag() { ... };
Tag tag2 = new Tag() { ... };

p.Tags.Add(new Tag_Photo_XREF { Tag = tag1 };
p.Tags.Add(new Tag_Photo_XREF { Tag = tag2 };

context.Photos.Add(p);
context.SaveChanges();
```

You don't need to add the Tag and Xref directly to the context because it is being added via the relationship you have defined.

You could probably make this easier on yourself by adding a helper method to your Photo class:

```
public class Photo
{
    // ...

    public void AddTag(Tag tagToAdd)
    {
        this.Tags.Add(new Tag_Photo_XREF { Tag = tagToAdd });
    }

    // ...
 }
```

That would take care of creating the Xref portion for you.

Comment: Thats great it answers half my question. Now to prevent duplication, i can handle it easily from a single DBContext but if there's 50,100,1000 operations all going on at he same time how to make sure a  duplicate tag doesn't get added? Doing it from a single DBContext is fine as you can check change tracker etc. I might need to ask a seperate question?

Comment: I'll ask this as a separate question. Thanks

Comment: I mentioned in the answer...you could add a unique index to your database. This would throw an error if you tried to insert a duplicate.